# Checkbox list without using submit

Tags: checkbox, submit, settings, form-submit, checkboxlist

if i have this code:

```
<div><input type="checkbox" name="lista[]" value="3424"> 3424<br><input type="checkbox" name="lista[]" value="3333"> 3333<br></div>
```

I would like to have the checkbox value in the variable $valore without using any submit button

help me?

Answer (score 0):

I'm very new with this. But it seems your case is similar to the one that I've found somewhere on the internet. Too bad, I don't remember that internet address.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<input class="calc" type="checkbox" name="lista[]" value="3424"> 3424<br>
<input class="calc" type="checkbox" name="lista[]" value="3333"> 3333<br>
</div>

<input type="text" name="sum"/>

<script>
    function calcscore(){
    var valore = 0;
    $(".calc:checked").each(function(){
        valore=parseInt($(this).val(),10);
    });
    $("input[name=sum]").val(valore.toLocaleString())
    //alert(valore)
    }
    $().ready(function(){
    $(".calc").change(function(){
        calcscore()
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[Test Link in jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/fr5vbe9u/).

I don't understand at all the code because I just copied it from the internet, then I try to modify it with more miss than hit.

The original code is to sum the value of the checked checkbox, so it put plus (+) sign in this line : `valore+=parseInt($(this).val(),10);`

Comment: i not can user "class="calc"" :(